# Put the last item in the listview at the bottom

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I'm working on a sidemenu listview and every item is this xml "rbm_item.xml" :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/rbm_item_height"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_topbottom"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_topbottom"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_leftright"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_leftright"    >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/rbm_item_icon"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/rbm_item_image_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/rbm_item_image_width"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
     />

<TextView         
    android:id="@+id/rbm_item_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rbm_item_text_size"
    android:textColor="@color/rbm_item_text_color"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rbm_item_text_padding_left"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/rbm_item_text_padding_top"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>

<TextView         
    android:id="@+id/rbm_item_text_sub"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rbm_item_text"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textSize="@dimen/rbm_item_text_sub_size"
    android:textColor="@color/rbm_item_text_sub_color"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rbm_item_text_sub_padding_left"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"/>
```

and i made an adapter for this listview items :

```
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.rbm_item, null);
        }

        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbm_item_icon);
        icon.setImageResource(getItem(position).iconRes);

        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rbm_item_text);
        title.setText(getItem(position).tag);

        TextView Description = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.rbm_item_text_sub);


        return convertView;
    }
```

and simply this is the list xml file "list.xml" :

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:divider="@color/rbm_divider_color"
android:dividerHeight="@dimen/rbm_divider_ht"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />
```

And the onCreateView function:

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
    }
```

And i add the items dynamically to the adapter `adapter.add(...)` by this function :

```
    public void parseXml(int menu) {
    try {
        adapter = new SampleAdapter(getActivity());
        XmlResourceParser xpp = getResources().getXml(menu);
        xpp.next();
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                String elemName = xpp.getName();
                if (elemName.equals("item")) {
                    String textId = xpp.getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "title");
                    String iconId = xpp.getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "icon");
                    String resId = xpp.getAttributeValue(
                        "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", "id");
                    String Desc = MainActivity.getItemDescription(resId);

                    //Log.i("", "parsing :" + Desc);
                    this.adapter.add(new SampleItem(textId, Integer.valueOf(iconId
                        .replace("@", "")), Desc));

                }

            }

            eventType = xpp.next();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log", "while parsing xml", e);
    }

    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And SampleItem is simple struct to contain the icon, title... properties, and the Menu parameter is the xml file that contain the items inside a `<menu>` tag and i itreat on them above and every on of them is like :

```
  <item android:id="@+id/ribbon_menu_profile" android:title="Profile" 
     android:icon="@drawable/profile"></item>
 .....
```

What I actually want is to put the last item of these items at the bottom of the list

I've searched a lot but I didn't find any View class method to do that if i supposed to set it by the convertView parameter in the getView function.

So is there any way to do that?

So I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Where is your ListView and Adapter implementation?

Comment: I'll edit the question and add them

Comment: @SteveBenett edited ! Is that enough ?

Comment: @walid so you want to sort your list in reverse order? is this correct?

Comment: No i just want put the last item of these itmes in the bottom of the listview layout and keep the rest at the top

Comment: @malimo i've added an image to describe what i want. And thanks in advance

Comment: it's now on the top with the other items and i want it to be at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try 
 listview.addFooterView(view);

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like this: just put your list in a relativeLayout and add an extra item below:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/lastStickyItem"    
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="@dimen/rbm_item_height"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_topbottom"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_topbottom"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_leftright"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/rbm_item_padding_leftright"    >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/rbm_item_icon"
android:layout_height="@dimen/rbm_item_image_height"
android:layout_width="@dimen/rbm_item_image_width"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
 />

<TextView         
android:id="@+id/rbm_item_text"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textSize="@dimen/rbm_item_text_size"
android:textColor="@color/rbm_item_text_color"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rbm_item_text_padding_left"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/rbm_item_text_padding_top"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"/>

<TextView         
android:id="@+id/rbm_item_text_sub"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@id/rbm_item_text"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:textSize="@dimen/rbm_item_text_sub_size"
android:textColor="@color/rbm_item_text_sub_color"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/rbm_item_text_sub_padding_left"
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="end"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_above="@id/lastStickyItem"
android:divider="@color/rbm_divider_color"
android:dividerHeight="@dimen/rbm_divider_ht"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/list_padding"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/list_padding" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

fill the extra (last) item inside your activity instead of the adapter...